# How to store/retrieve an NSMutableArray of objects?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

How do I store/retrieve an NSMutableArray of objects? The easy / fast way please. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what format you'd like to use. If you are fine with using [property lists](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/propertylists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1), then you can use [writeToFile](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile:atomically:) to save the array, and you can use [arrayWithContentsOfFile](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithContentsOfFile:) to load it back again.

Comment: This will only work if the objects in the array are property list objects.  Otherwise, the poster will have to use archiving.

Answer (score 1):

[Archiving?](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i)
Missed the iPhone tag, not sure if this will work on the iPhone or not.